# How to render an array.to_json with :include option in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In my controller I have :

```
def index
  # Array of Task objects
  @tasks = Task.get_tasks(current_user, params)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html

    # Sends correct JSON but not including the 'author' object in it
    # format.json { render :json => @tasks.to_json(:include => [:author]) }

    # With this the JSON look correct but is interpreted as a string in the JavaScript code
    format.json { render :json => @tasks.map { |e| e = e.to_json(:include => [:author]) } }
  end
end
```

Do you know any 'clean' solution to properly pass the `:include` option when rendering an array converted to JSON ?

**EDIT**

I am  using **MongoDB**

**EDIT (2)**

I updated from `mongoid (2.0.1)` to `mongoid (2.0.2)` and it works.
Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Are you sure? I've done some quick test with an array and it seems to work fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The to_json is redundant. I just tested it and with works with some similar code here using the syntax:

`format.json { render :json => @tasks, :include => [:author] }`

This is rails 3.0.7.  This is also assuming that author is set as a `belongs_to` of Task.

Comment: Hum ... In fact this works but only for the first object of the array :/ Other objects do not have the `author` object.

Comment: Bizarre. My example here has a huge list of items, and each has it's belongs_to embedded as appropriate.

Comment: Something that might be useful : I am using MongoDB ... :/

Comment: Oooh, interesting. So you're not using ActiveRecord. That may make the difference, but I'm not sure.